# How do I force r to print character strings with single quotes?

Tags: r, string, character, quotes, single-quotes

I'm writing some code that interfaces with SQL, and I need my character strings to print with single quotes, but R defaults to double quotes. When I go to ?Quotes, I don't see any guidance.

Any suggestions on how I can get the below character string to print as I'm typing it (with single quotes)?

```
help <- 'help me'
help

#Result :`-(
"help me"
```

Comment: The R parse doesn't remember what quotes you used. They don't make a difference to R. You can add single quotes to format the value and then `cat()` the result to prevent the usual quotes around strings: `cat(sQuote("help me", q=FALSE))`. But you can't change the default behavior of the parser/console.

Comment: Also, it seems very unlikely that you need R to print with single quotes to get it to interface with SQL. Can you give an example where this seems to be required?

Comment: @AllanCameron - Oracle SQL for instance interprets `'string'` as a character string but `"string"` as a column name `string`.

Comment: But it really doesn't matter what R prints to the console. You need the string itself to contain the quotes likely. The string value itself doesn't have any quotes in it. It's just a memory address that ends in a null byte in memory. Perhaps you can show how you are trying to build your SQL. Because the example you have now doesn't feel like a good reflection of what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Creating valid SQL statements programmatically is a common task in R. So, it is no surprise that there are already solutions available. Just to pick 2 Examples:

#### 1. sqldf

This example is taken from [G. Grothendiek's sqldf overview](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-5-insert-variables):

```
library(sqldf)
minSL <- 7
limit <- 3
species <- "virginica"
fn$sqldf("select * from iris where \"Sepal.Length\" > $minSL and species = '$species' limit $limit")
```

> ```
>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
> 1          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
> 2          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
> 3          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
> ```

#### 2. glue

This example is modified from `help("glue_sql", "glue")`:

```
library(glue)
library(magrittr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
iris2 <- iris
colnames(iris2) <- gsub("[.]", "_", tolower(colnames(iris)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris2)
var <- "sepal_width"
tbl <- "iris"
num <- 2
val <- "setosa"
glue_sql("
  SELECT {`var`}
  FROM {`tbl`}
  WHERE {`tbl`}.sepal_length > {num}
    AND {`tbl`}.species = {val}
  LIMIT {limit}
  ", limit = 4, .con = con)  %T>%
  print()%>% 
  DBI::dbGetQuery(con, .)
```

> ```
> <SQL> SELECT `sepal_width`
> FROM `iris`
> WHERE `iris`.sepal_length > 2
>   AND `iris`.species = 'setosa'
> LIMIT 4
>
>   sepal_width
> 1         3.5
> 2         3.0
> 3         3.2
> 4         3.1
> ```

#### 3. Other ressources

Perhaps, it might be worthwhile to study the help pages on *SQL quoting* (`?DBI::SQL`), or more low level: `sprintf()`.